# What kind of math do I need to become a better developer and programmer?

Tags: math

I'm at a community college currently and while our curriculum is pretty good, it lacks math or any real theory. If I ever want to create an algorithm for anything, I'm screwed. I'm essentially a code monkey.

Where do I even start in attaining a relevant theoretical background to complement my programming experience? What do I need to know?

Apologies if this is the wrong place to post this, I'm not sure where to post technical but not pure programming questions.

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com is the place you're after ;)

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Standard business logic doesn't involve a lot of math for say a hospital compared to a bank. It also depends on what kind of application you are writing.

Comment: If you're not doing anything game related then addition, subtraction, multiplication and division are probably all you need.

Comment: Unfortunately there really isn't a good place for open ended questions like this anywhere in the StackExchange network.  Best place would probably in [chat], but even then you might not get an answer, it all depends on if someone in chat at the time is able/willing to answer.

Comment: @Fogmeister - Any scientific or statistical programming would surely require math. Not game related at all.

Comment: Looking at the graphics and physics engines used by most gaming systems, I'd say the math required would be very sophisticated, indeed.  Not game related?  Hardly.

Comment: @duffymo - I did NOT say that math was NOT game related. Sigh. READ MY comment. I said that scientific and statistical programming are in general not game related (even though math will often be used in games.) Note that there is a huge amount of scientific/statistical programming done.

Comment: You don't have to explain it to me.  I read your comment.  I think it's poorly worded at best.

Answer (score 4):

Certain sects of elite programmers, notably Joel and therefore probably Fog Creek, seem to dismiss you if you aren't mathy. Others don't. Being great at math helps, but here's something that took me years to internalize: there are a lot of groups out there, many have deep biases, and you will never get them to unanimously agree that you are awesome.

So play to your strengths, never stop learning, and build amazing things. That's what matters!

Apparently that's what *my* sect believes. :)

Seriously though: I'm awful at math and I've had an extremely rewarding 12-year career. I've used evolutionary algorithms and I've pulled off solutions smart people said were impossible. I am deeply intuitive and creative, not linear. And I feel fine.

So to address your specific fear, I will say that even without ever having taken calculus or having read The Art of Programming, algorithms are fairly easy for me to get my head around. You can start learning the basics today, the knowledge is easy to find... Bubble sorts and shell sorts and what not are not magic, they are very simple snippets of code. I familiarized myself with big-O notation and algorithms because it's fascinating and because I want to be the best I can be, but let's be clear: big-O notation has never once been pivotal to my job, nor have I met many people who can carry a conversation about it.

So it depends on what you want to do.

3D game engines is probably the most math-intensive area I've touched... Search, AI, database engineering (read: building an actual database server) and other areas that require miraculous performance from vast servers are algorithm-intensive and benefit from a deep knowledge of math.

Common web development and business work requires... Maybe the first three weeks of high school algebra. If that. Seriously.

Taking some sort of algorithms computer science course and the pre-reqs (normally first-year calculus) is something you should do if you can, being smarter never hurts, but perhaps more importantly, some people fall in love with it and build a career around it. It's a part of most good CS programs.

But you can also do just fine without it. I dropped out of a community college English program to apprentice as a programmer, and I may want to go back some day, but for now I'm too busy learning things that are actually more relevant to my work than math.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do. Discrete math is good for the general reasoning involved with programming, and is my main recommendation. Linear algebra has applications in graphics and other fields. Statistics is crucial for machine learning.

It sounds like you should be taking CS courses though! Anything with "algorithms" or "theory of computing" in the title would be excellent. Otherwise there's many good courses available for free online through MIT, Stanford, and others.

Comment: Those types of courses are not offered where I go. Where I go sucks so hard, I'm on the brink of dropping out.

Comment: "It depends on what you want to do."  I couldn't agree more.  I took Discrete Math, Data Structures, and a couple classes on algorithms in school, and I haven't used much / any of it for the business programming I do.

Comment: Not offered where I go?  Do you have an Internet connection?  Have you not heard of MOOCs?  You can take linear algebra at MIT from Gil Strang.  Every class you need is on the web and free.  All they'll cost is your time and effort.